# Why the code does not Work? (Chrome api)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This code works perfectly

```
   chrome.storage.sync.get("test", function (array){
      var newArray = array["test"];
      newArray.push("newValue");

      chrome.storage.sync.set({"test": newArray});
   });
```

But this code does not work

```
      var key = "test";
      chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (array){
      var newArray = array[key];
      newArray.push("newValue");

      chrome.storage.sync.set({key: newArray});
   });
```

Why?

Comment: Globals not allowed?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Doh! Of course it's a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: Since you're using Chrome, you can use the third option in the accepted answer to the linked question, a computed property name: `chrome.storage.sync.set({[key]: newArray});` (note the `[...]` around `key`). See the linked question's answers for why what you did didn't work.